# Solving for intervals without using NumberLinePlot

Tags: equation-solving, intervals

I've been struggling to find a way to find an interval solution to an equation/inequality. I know mathematica can do this since for example,

```
NumberLinePlot[Sin[x] < 0.5, {x, 0, 6.28}]
```

gives a plot of the correct interval. How can I have mathematica just give me the Interval instead of the plot?

Comment: Like this? `Reduce[0 <= x <= 2 \[Pi] && Sin[x] < 1/2, x]`. The `||` symbol means `Or`.

Comment: `Reduce[Sin[x] < 1/2 && 0 < x < 2 π, x]` gives `0 < x < π/6 || (5*π)/6 < x < 2*π`. The `||` march refers is in the result.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks march and goldberg! Does mathematica have a built in function to convert the result into intervals? I can write a (sloppy) function for it myself but I'd rather use built-in functions.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

```
foo = Reduce[{
    Sin[x] < 1/2,
    0 <= x <= 2 π
  }, x, Reals]
(* 0 <= x < π/6 || (5 π)/6 < x <= 2 π *)
```

almost gives you what you want.  We can rewrite this to be in interval form,

```
ineqsToIntervals[x_Or] := List @@ (
    x /. {
      Inequality[a_, Less, _, Less, b_] :> 
        Row[{"(", a, ",", b, ")"}],
      Inequality[a_, LessEqual, _, Less, b_] :> 
        Row[{"[", a, ",", b, ")"}],
      Inequality[a_, Less, _, LessEqual, b_] :> 
        Row[{"(", a, ",", b, "]"}],
      Inequality[a_, LessEqual, _, LessEqual, b_] :> 
        Row[{"[", a, ",", b, "]"}]
    }
)
```

so that `ineqsToIntervals[foo]` gives $\{ [0,\frac{\pi}{6}), (\frac{5\pi}{6},2\pi] \}$.

Comment: Note: you do not need to specify the domain to `Reduce`. The inequality `0 <= x <= 2 π` is sufficient to tell `Reduce` it is working over the reals.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might try

```
List @@ (Drop[#, {2, -2}]& /@ List @@@ Reduce[Sin[x] < 1/2 && 0 < x < 2 π, x])
```

> `{{0, π/6}, {(5 π)/6, 2 π}}`